# Surface view get pixel value class cast error in ontouchevnt

Tags: android, view, surfaceview, touch-event

i want to get pixel value when i touch my screen. its in a class which extends a surfaceview

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {View v =this;
        ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)x,(int)y);


        }
```

i am getting class cast exception error in

> ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);

what i done wrong here. plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is "this", is it a reference to an ImageView ?

Which class is this code ? An Activity class ?

You need to provide more peace of code to we help you.

Probably "this" is an Activity context reference and you can't cast it to an ImageView.

try it

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.XXXX)
```

where XXXX is your ImageView ID

**Addition**

```
        for (View objView : this.getTouchables()){
        if (objView instanceof ImageView){
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)objView;
            //...
        }
    }
```

You can do this if your surfaceView only has one ImageView on it. If you have more than one, you'll probably need extra informations about it like it's id/tag.

Comment: it is a surface view extended class . 
i am drawing on canvas

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't pay attention about it.
So, "this" probably is an surfaceView reference not a ImageView reference. Try to do what I said, SurfaceView have the "findViewById" too. But tell me if your imageView is created dynamically.

Comment: its created dynamically, i dont use any xml